Up to what radius/distance/area maximum do weather parameters remain constant?
Up to what radius/distance/area maximum do weather parameters remain constant? For example, precipitation is so variable that it can vary even within a few meters, while sunshine durations may not change/remain constant for much longer distances. For a project of mine, I need to know approximately up to what radius/distance/area maximum do different weather parameters remain constant including temperature, precipitation, humidity, wind speed, wind direction, humidity, cloud cover, evapotranspiration, soil moisture, soil temperature, and air quality.

I think you have answered your own question - it depends on the parameter, and on the region and time of year. For instance in the UK winter rainfall is from weather fronts and is less variable spatially than summer convective rainfall. Temperatures are more variable in hilly regions than on plains. I suggest you look at high resolution gridded data (e.g. https://crudata.uea.ac.uk/cru/data/hrg/) and then look at its spatial variability geostatistically for your area of interest.

To have people even attempt at a ballpark, you'd definitely need to better define what you mean by constant (10% change?  1%?)  And even then, a best guess only seems possible if talking about nearly flat regions outside of certain weather phenomena (hurricanes and fronts for example have large changes in some values in a very small distance)

As phrased, this question is rather too broad.  It can vary from centimetres (difference between a place struck by lightning or not) to hundreds of km (upper tropospheric humidity), and of course depends on what you mean by "constant".  There is constantly no tornado for thousands of kms in most of the world most of the time.  You can't really derive your answer from models, because their spatial resolution is too limited, nor from in-situ point measurements.  I think you might need to reconsider what you really need for your project, or adjust your project aims.

For that, you must know the scale of the features that affect the parameters. The spatial and temporal scales of these features can vary. And by 'constant,' you must be sure what you mean. How much variation is okay for you? The figure below may help you understand the scales.

the above figure is taken from- Tavakolifar, Hamed & Shahghasemi, Ebrahim & Nazif, Sara. (2017). Evaluation of climate change impacts on extreme rainfall events characteristics using a synoptic weather typing-based daily precipitation downscaling model. Journal of Water and Climate Change. 8. jwc2017107. 10.2166/wcc.2017.107
The figure can be found in other sources, too.

Got a refetence for the figure?

@planetmaker the above figure is taken from: Tavakolifar, Hamed & Shahghasemi, Ebrahim & Nazif, Sara. (2017). Evaluation of climate change impacts on extreme rainfall events characteristics using a synoptic weather typing-based daily precipitation downscaling model. Journal of Water and Climate Change. 8. jwc2017107. 10.2166/wcc.2017.107.
But you can find plenty of other sources too.

Yes-ish. But figures you didn't make yourself need attribution - and links to sources also improve your answer as they make it easier to follow your thoughts or dive in deeper :) (thus preferrably: edit your answer with what you wrote in the comment, and actually linking the cited paper)

@planetmaker I have edited the answer with a reference and a link to the paper.
